# Call a function from nav bar directive which is ABOVE the scope of the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My app has a navigation bar directive which sits just below ng-app and just above ng-view

```
<body ng-app="outflankApplicationApp">

<navigation-bar></navigation-bar>

<div class="main-container" ng-view=""></div>
```

The nav bar has buttons which sit on either the left or right hand side. Currently, the buttons are tied to functions on the scope of the directive in the link function.

What I need to do is to add buttons which have the ability to call functions from the controller of a page. I am not able to simply call them as an inherited scope as the nav bar directive is ABOVE the ng-view.

The template:

```
<div class="nav-bar bg-primary">

<div class="nav-bar-left-component">
    <button ng-click="goBack()" class="btn back-button nav-bar-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
    </button>
    <button ng-click="startEditMode()" class="edit-button nav-bar-button">
        <b>Edit</b>
    </button>
    <button ng-click="finishEditMode()" class="done-button nav-bar-button">
        <b>Done</b>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="nav-bar-right-component">
    <button navigation-goto-push="/settings" class="settings-button nav-bar-button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The directive:

```
    angular
.module('outflankApplicationApp')
.directive('navigationBar', [
    '$rootScope',
    'NavigationStackService',
    'NavigationBarService',
    function ($rootScope, NavigationStackService, NavigationBarService) {

        function link(scope, element) {

            var backButton = element.find('.back-button');
            backButton.hide();

            var settingsButton = element.find('.settings-button');
            settingsButton.hide();

            var editButton = element.find('.edit-button');
            editButton.hide();

            var doneButton = element.find('.done-button');
            doneButton.hide();

            scope.showNavigationBar = true;

            scope.goBack = function(){
                NavigationStackService.popState();
            };

            scope.startEditMode = function(){
                NavigationBarService.hideNavigationEdit();
                NavigationBarService.showNavigationDone();

                $rootScope.$emit('editMode', {
                    'started': true
                });
            };

            scope.finishEditMode = function(){
                NavigationBarService.hideNavigationDone();
                NavigationBarService.showNavigationEdit();

                $rootScope.$emit('editMode', {
                    'started': false
                });
            };

            //event listener for the back button
            $rootScope.$on('navigationStack', function(event, e){

                if('over1item' in e){
                    if(e.over1item){
                        backButton.show();
                    }else{
                        backButton.hide();
                    }
                }

            });

            //event listener for the navigationBar event
            $rootScope.$on('navigationBar', function(event, e){

                if('show' in e){
                    if(e.show){
                        element.show();
                    }else{
                        element.hide();
                    }
                }

                if('showSettings' in e){
                    if(e.showSettings){
                        settingsButton.show();
                    }else{
                        settingsButton.hide();
                    }
                }

                if('showEdit' in e){
                    if(e.showEdit){
                        editButton.show();
                    }else{
                        editButton.hide();
                    }
                }

                if('showDone' in e){
                    if(e.showDone){
                        doneButton.show();
                    }else{
                        doneButton.hide();
                    }
                }

            });
        }


        return {
            templateUrl: 'templates/navigation-bar.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: link
        };
    }
]);
```

Any thing more I need to add, let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where did you receive `$rootScope.$emit('editMode'`

Comment: subscribe for the emit event inside your controller.like this  $rootScope.$on('editMode',function(){});

Comment: Ahh ok so I add something to the $rootScope and when it's turned on, it will trigger the function in the controller, yes?

Comment: when you broadcast something it'll trigger `$on`

Comment: obviously yes.check out the proper syntax

Comment: instead of doing emitting do broadcasting.bcse if u emit the contollers above the directive can only be able to detect the change.in ur case you need to do broadcasting.which will do from top to bottom

Comment: Thank you, you guys are awesome! One more question, how do I pass the controllers $scope properties UP to the directive in order to utilise ng-show etc?

Comment: use $scope.emit it will do emit from bottom to top to ur directive.and also subscribe in ur directive for that emit event