# Best way to toggle Booleans between $rootScope and and a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a navbar directive which sits above ng-view. It utilises the $rootScope to trigger events to show buttons in certain views.

I am trying to add a button to the directive template which will switch a boolean in a controller for a particular view. The view shows a period of time and each period has a particular boolean that I want to switch from the directive.

The boolean value is saved in a local storage object which is initialized when each iteration of this particular view is loaded.

First, the value needs to be communicated to the directive so the button can display as being set to true or false. When the switch is toggled, the value of that boolean needs to make its way from the directive, through the $rootScope, to the controller and then be saved in the storage object.

When the view is changed, the whole process needs to repeat. The switch needs to be able to be switched on and off multiple times, obviously.

At present, I am emitting the value from the controller to the $rootScope and then listening for that value in the directive link function.

However, what is the best way to get that $rootScope value BACK into the controller. I tried setting up a $rootScope.$watch in the controller which appeared to work on any single page but when navigating between different time periods, the $rootScope value of the boolean was not resetting properly.

I tried resetting the value in the controller initialization as follows:

```
$rootScope.booleanValue = false;
```

but this didn't work.

I have also tried the following:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (next, current) {

        $rootScope.booleanValue = false;

    });
```

but I can't get the whole cycle to work properly. It still seems as though the value of the property in the $rootScope is not resetting from the view before and is then carrying over when an adjacent pay period view is loaded.

I hope this makes sense. I will save you from too much code as I think the basic idea is here.

Comment: What type of scope does the navbar directive use? false, true, or isolate?

Comment: There is a property in the return object of scope: {}, which suggests an isolated scope, but scope is injected into the link function so I'm not sure which one.

Comment: The link function isn't injectable. Are you saying you are using the first argument of the link function? Or does your directive has a controller with its own scope? Maybe it would be better to post the relevant portions of your navbar directive. Then maybe we can see how to share its state with your views?

Comment: Yes the first argument of the link function is scope. There are then functions attached to this.

Please see this question which I asked previously which contains most of the code:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704658/call-a-function-from-nav-bar-directive-which-is-above-the-scope-of-the-page?noredirect=1#comment57155951_34704658

Comment: this happens to be one of the many drawbacks to using `$rootScope`.  It is a common misconception that `$rootScope` is some sort of "global" parent object, when in fact it is what `$scope` prototypically inherit from, and prototype inheritance is more complex than just something being "globally" accessible.  You should use factories or services to share application state information, since these are singleton objects.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is share state from your navbar directive (an isolate scope) and your view's controller. I recommend you use a **factory provider** service to share that state:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('navbarState', function (){
    return {started: false}
});
```

In your navbar directive, inject the service and store the state in that service:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('navigationBar', [
    '$rootScope',
    'navbarState',
    //'NavigationStackService',
    //'NavigationBarService',
    function ($rootScope, navbarState) {

        function link(scope, element) {

           scope.startEditMode = function(){
                console.log("Edit clicked");
                navbarState.started=true;
                //NavigationBarService.hideNavigationEdit();
                //NavigationBarService.showNavigationDone();
            };

            scope.finishEditMode = function(){
                console.log("Done clicked");
                navbarState.started=false;
                //NavigationBarService.hideNavigationDone();
                //NavigationBarService.showNavigationEdit();
            };
        }
        return {
            templateUrl: 'templates/navigation-bar.html',
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {},
            link: link
        };
    }
]);
```

In your view controller, retrieve the service, put it on the controller's scope, and use it in your template.

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('controller2', function(navbarState) {
    console.log("view controller2 started");
    var vm = this;
    vm.navState = navbarState;
    vm.message = "hello from ct2";
});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5k64yqk/).